# Sharepoint Custom Form : Modify font for description

Tags: css, custom-form

Good Morning Again;

I have built a custom form using SPD 2013 OP with SPD2013.

When you enter a description in the custom list settings, the description displays under the input box on the custom form.

What is the attriube / element to modify the font / style of this text?

Thanks

Comment: you can use the f12 button and use DEV tools to find that.

Comment: Try to inspect the field description by right clicking on element and choosing option (inspect element). You can get the class or ID of the description element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the font of the field's description on the new or edit form with this css (this just changes the font color to red, so tweak it according to your needs):

```
<style>
.ms-formbody > .ms-metadata
{
 color: red;
}
</style>
```

If you want to apply the changes only on some fields' description, you can do that with javascript.

Comment: Hi Damjan, Can you add hyperlink in description?